# Exchange telephone number for user id in Telegram

Tags: java, authentication, groovy, telegram

I wrote a Telegram Bot in groovy and it was a piece of cake.

Now in order to register propper webhooks I need to get a hold of user's id.

I read, that I should call [auth.sendCode](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode) method to start that process.

Are there any simpler alternatives to that?

If not, how can I invoke the `sendCode` with the smallest effort and possibly w/o any additional dependencies? Any examples or pointers using plain java or curl would be good.

Comment: what you are trying to do is not quite clear from your question.

Comment: get telegram user id, that's it

Comment: you can get that as users start using your BOT, you may not need  the Full Telegram API

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: when a user starts using your bot, you get his user_id as part of the data you receive. The message object contains a user property object, the user_id is available from that user object.

Comment: I know that. I need to be able to match the telegram user id to the user id of my system. So, my user should create this mapping explicitly

Comment: your user can send in a key that helps you map them directly to their telegram ID

Comment: I ended up implementing `/login 1122334` method in my bot, if this was what you meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147597/discussion-between-charles-okwuagwu-and-injecteer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I ended up with a simple solution.

Instead of authenticating against the Telegram API over MTProto, I reversed the process. I implemented a new bot-command:

```
/login {my-user-id}
```

so that the user sends his id (can be some generated token later) in Telegram bot chat and the bot sends this message - along with Telegram user id! - over webhook to my server, where I do the matching and saving.

The implementation looks like this:

```
switch( json.message.text ){
  case ~/\/login \w+/: 
    String userId
    text.toLowerCase().eachMatch( /\/login (\w+)/ ){ userId = it[ 1 ] }
    String telegramUserId = json.message.from.id
    saveJoin userId, telegramUserId
    break
 }
```